# Object.defineProperty not changing property of element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to override the `src` property of all iframes in my application so their `src` property always gets set to "redirect.html" regardless of what value the HTML tag defines for it.
So far, I have come up with the following, but it doesn't seem to be applying to the DOM element:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var propertyDescriptorSrc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLIFrameElement.prototype, "src");
        Object.defineProperty(HTMLIFrameElement.prototype, "src", {
            get: function get_src() {
                var val = propertyDescriptorSrc.get.call(this);
                return "redirect.html";
            },
            set: function (val) {
                alert('setting: ' + val);
                propertyDescriptorSrc.set.call(this, val);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="page.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the iframe element in the body to load redirect.html instead of page.html, since I overrided its "getter", but it still loaded page.html.
Is there a way to force this behavior where all iframes by default go to redirect.html instead of whatever is defined in their `src` attribute?

(This is just an experimental project)

Comment: `HTMLIFrameElement.prototype` is not used by the browser when evaluating an iframe. It is only the DOM interface from JavaScript to the actual data. Adding (or overwriting) a getter doesn't affect the internal browser data.

Comment: What is it using then? Can that be modified in this manner?

Comment: I think it will "sort-of" work if you programmatically *create* the iframe after overriding its property, e.g. `document.createElement('iframe')`.  I don't think it will work on iframes already part of the DOM.  Run your code in your browsers console, then create an iframe.  You can test it by setting the `src` programmatically.

Comment: @Amy is there a way to apply it to dom elements? Or maybe first define the property for iframe so when the dom is parsed, it uses the new property of src and ignores the one that is specific there?

Comment: Aside from using JS to find, duplicate, and replace the DOM elements, I don't think so.  But if you're going to do that, it's easier to simply find those elements and replace their `src` attribute, as your sole answer demonstrates.

Comment: While I think your question is interesting, to be honest, ultimately it isn't worth it, in my opinion.  Duplicating the DOM elements will be super difficult to get right (you'd have to get all the attached event handlers and re-bind them to the new element), and other JS might retain references to those elements, but not their replacements... It sounds like fertile ground for bugs.  Simply setting their `src` attribute would be *far* safer and less error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

Before it starts javascript, the DOM tree is already parsed and contains all iframes together with its src, according to the Critical Rendering Path.
The only way to do this is by using javascript to redefine the src attributes of the individual iframe node. For example, as below.

all iframes are set to redirect.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="page.html"></iframe>
    <iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
<script>
( function(){
    var lng = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length;
    for (var i=0; i<lng;i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i].src="redirect.html";
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the suggestion, @Aaron Digulla gives a more readable form of function.
It seems that the search algorithms of the DOM tree are so efficient today that the argument is the readability of the record, not the efficiency.

```
    (function(){
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i=0; i<frames.length;i++){
        frames[i].src="redirect.html";
    }
    })();
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` is an expensive call. You should assign it to a local array and then iterate over this array instead of calling this many times.

Comment: @Aarin Digulla  This is just a quick example. You're absolutely right.

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of people will just copy&paste your example.

Comment: @Aarin Digulla  You're right. However, after profiling both versions, it appears that the presented solution is faster by 49 ms than the solution with the assignment of an array for 10,000 iterations in the FF browser. It's within the limits of statistical error. You can check the profile because maybe I've made an error somewhere.

Comment: I didn't expect these results. How big was the DOM?

Comment: The DOM tree is minimal, as in the example. For a small DOM, finding nodes *can be* faster than the reference. I think this may be an interesting topic for discussion, but it is not related to the topic.